# Sitecore get list of all languages

Tags: c#, sitecore

How do I programatically get a list of all the languages available?
I am using the following code:

```
Item currentItem = GetCurrentItem();

LanguageCollection languages;
Database database = Context.ContentDatabase;
languages = LanguageManager.GetLanguages(database);
```

This does not return all the languages installed on the system and available in the languagedefinitions.config file.

Any idea on how to get all the languages?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the list of all language definitions from the `<languageDefinitions>/<languages>` setting, you can use the following code:

```
Sitecore.Globalization.LanguageDefinitions.Definitions
```

The code which you use (`LanguageManager.GetLanguages(database);`) returns languages which are in the selected database under the `sitecore/system/languages` node only.

Comment: Thanks but that did not get every language in the LanguageDefinitions.config file for me. It just gets the languages that are available in the languages dropdown. For now, I am reading the config file and adding all the languages programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Late addition to this question - but if useful - Sitecore Powershell option below:

```
# Get languages:
$availableLanguages = [Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager]::GetLanguages([Sitecore.Context]::ContentDatabase)
$availableLanguages | Format-Table -Property *
```

Answer (score -1):

For now, I am reading the languagedefinitions.config file and adding all the languages programmatically.

Comment: Can you add some detail about how you did this? Perhaps a code sample?